# select json data using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to select page name data from this json file. I get the following error when I try to select data.name from this json :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

```js
[{
    "user_name": "Mohamed Salah",
    "user_id": "108037121206153",
    "user_pic": "https://scontent.fcai20-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.3008-1/2767035_114344183370_78d=0&_nc_ht=scontent.fcai20-4.fna&oh=00_AT_Fd-DYQzXZdhFtcYT5nMr1l72lCCvFvPLQEBCDu5Ng&oe=626C8346"
  },
  {
    "data": [{
        "name": "Page2",
        "access_token": "aadsada",
        "id": "1014557611"
      },
      {
        "name": "Page Share1",
        "access_token": "aadsada",
        "id": "101709879197276"
      },
      {
        "name": "Page Share3",
        "access_token": "aadsada",
        "id": "1552139415"
      },
      {
        "name": "Page Share2",
        "access_token": "aadsada",
        "id": "1552139415"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "MTAxNDQ3OTMyNTU3NjEx",
        "after": "MTE0MjMyODc3OTI3NjQ2"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I tried out the code below but it doesn't work

This is my jQuery code:

```js
$("#loadData").click(function(event) {
      var fetchApipages = 'http://localhost/social-control/fetchPages.php?fpages=true&access=EAAAAUaZA8jlABAPHhnwprWCLXG39ejJUh0quyilWVs2HwZAcVeKV9J9t4vu6ZCnJEMWmRtE9lMymKEp1KZBbt1XO3JINfjuZBK9OdvYydrZAZAIbxtX4Wqv8szrx6NPsc9DMqgYtZAjr11AG9VZA2NN2t2CtI6o7cZCRGIlGdLKjaPeKd3Y8WoE9t9Q1kuRyHReb4ZD';
      $.getJSON(fetchApipages, function(obj) {
        $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
          $("#pages").append("<option>" + value.data.name + "</option>");
        });
      });
```

Comment: @LeeTaylor i get this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Comment: `data` is an array. You will need to access it like `data[0].name`

Comment: @LeeTaylor the error disappear but not work , not getting anything

Comment: You are iterating over your outer array but assuming that each element contains the same contents. Your first element contains an object that has `user_name` etc. But you are attempting to access `data` from it.

Comment: I'd seriously recommend learning how to use your browser's debugging tools and inspecting the value that is in your json result. You will soon see what you are currently doing will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to loop through your outer array and assuming that all elements of that array contain and element called `data`. They do not. See my demo:

```js
var obj = [{
    "user_name": "Mohamed Salah",
    "user_id": "108037121206153",
    "user_pic": "https://scontent.fcai20-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.3008-1/2767035_114344183370_78d=0&_nc_ht=scontent.fcai20-4.fna&oh=00_AT_Fd-DYQzXZdhFtcYT5nMr1l72lCCvFvPLQEBCDu5Ng&oe=626C8346"
  },
  {
    "data": [{
        "name": "Page2",
        "access_token": "aadsada",
        "id": "1014557611"
      },
      {
        "name": "Page Share1",
        "access_token": "aadsada",
        "id": "101709879197276"
      },
      {
        "name": "Page Share3",
        "access_token": "aadsada",
        "id": "1552139415"
      },
      {
        "name": "Page Share2",
        "access_token": "aadsada",
        "id": "1552139415"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "MTAxNDQ3OTMyNTU3NjEx",
        "after": "MTE0MjMyODc3OTI3NjQ2"
      }
    }
  }
];

// This code assumes that you have loaded the json data somehow (I've hard-coded it above)
for(let page of obj[1].data)
{
  $("#pages").append("<option>" + page.name + "</option>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="pages"></select>
```